# Why if I search the exact address for a restaurant, does the places API not return the associated information for that restaurant?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Why if I search the exact address for a restaurant, does the places API not return the associated information for that restaurant?

For example, this is the address for a McDonald's pulled from a google search: "146 Tremont St, Boston, MA 02111".

If I do a search on the google Places API, it doesn't return that this is the address for a McDonald's which is what I'd expect.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJgdzSI51w44kRROxVqUqfoAg&fields=name,types,website&key=

Front end google search:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the place ID `ChIJgdzSI51w44kRROxVqUqfoAg` has a type `premise`, so it doesn't represent a business, but only the building on the map.

In order to solve your issue I would suggest using the [Find place](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) requests from Places API web service. So you can send a request

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=146%20Tremont%20St%2C%20Boston%2C%20MA%2002111&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry,name,place_id&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This request will return the following response

```
{
  "candidates":[
    {
      "formatted_address":"146 Tremont St, Boston, MA 02111, USA",
      "geometry":{
    "location":{
      "lat":42.3552225,"lng":-71.0630429
    },
    "viewport":{
      "northeast":{
        "lat":42.35661577989272,"lng":-71.06177427010728
      },
      "southwest":{
        "lat":42.35391612010728,"lng":-71.06447392989273
      }
    }
      },
      "name":"McDonald's",
      "place_id":"ChIJe645PYNw44kR_0ilqhElTKw"
    }
  ],
  "debug_log":{
    "line":[

    ]
  },
  "status":"OK"
}
```

As you can see this is expected McDonald's place.

I hope this helps!